# How to deny checking list of running processes?

Tags: linux, process

How to prevent a user from checking list of processes started by another user ?

In other words, how do I forbid a user to see which processes are running by another user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve that.

The oldest I know would be using a kernel with [grsecurty](https://grsecurity.net/) patches applied, which bring [restrictions for `procfs`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Grsecurity/Appendix/Grsecurity_and_PaX_Configuration_Options#Restrict_.2Fproc_to_user_only)

Another one would be the PID namespace feature of [`cgroups`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups#Namespace_isolation).

And the latest one the [`hidepid` feature of `procfs`](http://www.openwall.com/lists/kernel-hardening/2011/11/15/3).

When available, I'd go for the last one, as it is the least intrusive one.